# UK Ancestry Visa to retire

Tags: united-kingdom, ancestry

I have lived in the UK for 9 years prior on UK ancestry. My question is : 
Can I apply for UK ancestry so that I can retire permanently in the UK. I have my own means of financial support and also receive a UK old age pension.

Comment: Are you in the UK now?

Answer (score 1):

According to [UK Ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa):

> You can apply for a UK Ancestry visa if you:
>
> - are able and planning to work in the UK

It's unclear from your question whether the 9 years of living in the UK was recently (i.e. you still live there) or some time ago, and you are currently living somewhere else. This will make a difference for what you are eligible for.

Although the Ancestry visa does not appear to be available for retirement, there may be other visas you are eligible for. See [Find out if you can apply to settle in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk) and fill in answers for your circumstances to see what options there are.

Comment: That "find out" link is for someone in the UK to determine whether they can apply for ILR.  It doesn't seem particularly helpful in this case.

Comment: @phoog: I'm not entirely clear on whether the OP is in the UK right now or not.

Comment: You're right, that does not appear to be clear from the question.

Comment: Wife and I lived in the uk from 1986 to 1994 and returned to Australia, however we did not return to the uk on holidays for at least 6 years and it was just for holidays. WE currently holiday in the UK for 6 months in every 12 months and have been doing that for the past 4 years. WE applied for " Returning Resident" but was refused. That episode cost us $10,000 aud.  Now we would just like to live in our mobile home in the UK and be totally self sufficient not relying on the UK government for any assistance. We both receive the UK old age pension.